# asp.net How to insert record into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am having difficulties on getting my insert method to work correctly. I am new to back end development so any suggestions or comments will be helpful.

```
public Boolean insertDefaultUser()
    {
        Boolean flag = true;
        Users newUser = new Users();
        newUser.alias = "bulby";
        newUser.password = "chicken";
        newUser.email = "r@hot.com";

        dbc.Users.AddObject(newUser);   // ERROR !
        dbc.SaveChanges();
        return flag;

    }
```

However, on the *"add object line"* it gives me the follow error --->

```
Error "The best overloaded method match for System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<Guild_Chat.User>.AddObject(Guild_Chat.User)' has some invalid arguments ".
```

Comment: the error is suggesting that the type of argument in `dbc.Users.AddObject` is not of type which it is expecting ie `Guild_Chat.User`.

Comment: please show us the parameters that AddObject is expected to accept

Comment: You are creating and adding an entity of type Users and not User.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question but you should never save passwords in clear text.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the actual entity type `Guild_Chat.User`, for example:

```
public bool InsertDefaultUser()
{
    try
    {
       Guild_Chat.User newUser = new Guild_Chat.User
                              {
                                 alias = "bulby",
                                 password = "chicken",
                                 email = "r@hot.com"
                              };
       dbc.Users.AddObject(newUser);
       dbc.SaveChanges();
       return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try when i get home and I will update my comment.